# Does a ConcurrentHashMap need to be wrapped in a synchronized block?

Tags: java, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

Do all non-retreival operations on a ConcurrentHashMap (`put()`, `remove()` etc.) need to be wrapped in a `synchronized(this)` block?  I understand that all of these operations are thread-safe, so is there any real benefit/need in doing so?  The only operations used are `put()` and `remove()`.

```
protected final Map<String, String> mapDataStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

public void updateDataStore(final String key, final String value) {
    ...
    synchronized (this) {
        mapDataStore.put(key, value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No, you are losing the benefits of `ConcurrentHashMap` by doing that. You may as well be using a `HashMap` with `synchronized` or `synchronizedMap()` to lock the whole table (which is what you do when wrapping operations in `synchronized`, since the monitor implied is the entire object instance.)

The purpose of `ConcurrentHashMap` is to increase the throughput of your concurrent code by allowing concurrent read/writes on the table without locking the entire table. The table supports this internally by using lock striping (multiple locks instead of one, with each lock assigned to a set of hash buckets - see [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) by Goetz et al).

Once you are using `ConcurrentHashMap`, all standard map methods (`put()`, `remove()`, etc.) become atomic by virtue of the lock striping etc. in the implementation.  The only tradeoffs are that methods like `size()` and `isEmpty()` may not necessarily return accurate results, since the only way they could would be for all operations to lock the whole table.

The [`ConcurrentMap` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface also adds new atomic compound operations like `putIfAbsent()` (put something only if it the key is not already in the map), `remove()` accepting both key and value (remove an entry only if its value equals a parameter you pass), etc. These operations used to require locking the whole table because they needed two method calls to accomplish (e.g. `putIfAbsent()` would need calls to both `containsKey()` and `put()`, wrapped inside one `synchronized` block, if you were using a standard `Map` implementation.) Once again, you gain greater throughput using these methods, by avoiding locking the entire table.

Answer (score 15):

Synchronizing those operations has no benefit here - it actually degrades performance if you don't need synchronization.

The reason `ConcurrentHashMap` was created, is that synchronized maps (either implemented by hand like in the question or instantiated in the usual way with `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`) show bad performance when accessed by many threads. Put and get operations are blocking, so all other threads have to wait and can't access the map concurrently. The `ConcurrentHashMap` - as the name suggest - allows concurrent access on the other hand. You lose this benefit if you add synchronization.

Comment: What if a code-block contain both containsKey() and put() method? Should that be synchronized or not?

Comment: @gaurav That should probably be synchonized. But instead of synchronize I would rather use the methods `putIfAbsent` or `computeIfAbsent` (which both are atomic operations for ConcurrentMap).

Comment: 2: And what could the option if one is using Java 1.7?